# Capitalization of Type in Type I error

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am curious whether the "Type" in "Type I" error should be capitalized, or whether it should be rendered as "type I". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_I_error) appears to use the lower case, but this seems to be the [arbitrary choice of one editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Capitalization_of_the_terms_type_I_and_type_II_errors). I did a brief search of Wasserman's *All of Statistics* and found mixed capitalization (upper case in some tables, lower case in the index). *Elements of Statistical Learning* seems to use mostly capitalized.

I anticipate this question will be downvoted for not having a right answer. However, perhaps answers could serve as a kind of poll of whether users prefer capitalized Type or not.

Comment: [Google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22type+I+error%22%2C%22Type+I+error%22&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) indicates that capitalized is more prevalent than uncapitalized. However, some of the effect may be due to cases where 'Type' is the first word of a sentence, and thus capitalized.

Comment: I avoid this term because it's so arbitrary that it's difficult for a reader to remember what it means.  If I had to use it, I suppose capitalization would be preferable.  How about "tYpE 1"? ;).

Comment: [I believe you can subtract the cases in which 'Type' is the first word in a sentence on ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28Type+I+error+-+_START_+Type+I+error%29%2Ctype+I+error&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Type%20I%20error%20-%20%20_START_%20Type%20I%20error%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctype%20I%20error%3B%2Cc0). Also, if you search for "Type I error" in quotation marks, you are literally searching for occurrences in quotation marks. You need to drop them to get the correct result.

Comment: @Jan : thank you for sharing your ngram skills: those plots look far less ambiguous than what I had found.